# Sphinx documentation: translation (i18n) of conf.py variables

Tags: python, internationalization, python-sphinx

In a sphinx documentation project, how to add translations to the variables defined in `conf.py`?

Case in point: The `project` Variable is `"<Brand Name> Setup and Configuration Manual"`, where I would like to have the latter part translated.

Using the standard i18n facilities, those values are missing from the `.pot` files. I also could not find out how to get at the commandline-specified language within `conf.py` (to translate via hardcoded dictionary).

Comment: Did you read the docs for [internationalization](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/advanced/intl.html)?

Comment: Yes of course. I did not find an answer to above question. If there is one, please point me to the particular section.

Comment: There is an issue about this: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1260

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments above, this is currently an open issue.

It is possible to pass information to conf.py (only) by means of tags.

On the commandline, use `-t language_de` instead of `-D language=de`, in order to define a tag containing the locale id.

In `conf.py`, catch the tag by using:

```
language = None
for t in tags:
    if t.startswith('language_'):
        language = t[9:]
```

The `-D language=..` command line can then be omitted, since the `language` variable in `conf.py` has the same effect.

Once we got the language value, translation can be done with a dictionary:

```
project = {
    'de': u'<Brand Name> Setup-und Konfigurationshandbuch',
    # ... more translations ...
}.get(language, u'<Brand Name> Setup and Configuration Manual')
```