# Multilingual copyright documentation in several languages

Tags: configuration, internationalization, python-sphinx, copyright-display

Our documentation made with Sphinx is in two languages (as explained [here](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/advanced/intl.html)). We would like to be able to translate the copyright (at the bottom of the page) as well. However, the copyright is set in the configuration (`copyright = "2020, myself and others"` in conf.py) file in a unique version.

We would like to have something else for the French version (for example, `"2020, moi et les autres"`). Aside from modifying all the HTML files by hand, what is the best solution?

Comment: Related *["Sphinx documentation: translation (i18n) of conf.py variables"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55808716)*.